# Tooltip in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

What is the easiest way to include a tooltip in the gridView column?

For example in this column

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="short_comment" HeaderText="Comments" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="short_comment"/>
```

I would like to have something like

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="short_comment" ToolTipDataField="longer_comment"/>
```

Obviously the `ToolTipDataField` does not exist, but what would be the easiest way to achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replaced with template

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="short_comment">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("short_comment") %>' ToolTip ='<%# Bind("longer_comment") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

e.Row.Cells[7].ToolTip = e.Row.Cells[7].Text;

i did something like that it seems worked. What i do is to show the content of cell as a tool tip. You can put some longer comments here.

I handled situtation from codebehind. No sure it is best solution.

hope it helps.