# How to get a Tooltip for GridView headers from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` which is completely user defined. The first column of the `GridView` is from the `ListBox1`. The headers are defined using `ListBox2`.

For each and every header text of the `GridView`, correspondingly I have stored a line of text in a table in database.

How to use that line as tooltip for the header of `GridView`. FYI : Differenrt header columns has different line of text stored in the database table.

I have attached a screenshot which will tell what exactly I have achieved and what I am expecting. Thank you in advance, Kindly help.

http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/2083/47621961.jpg

As in the image I have retrieved first column of database table(referring to GridView1) in a ListBox2 and then using that ListBox to display as headers.

Here is the code how I am doing that:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow rw = default(DataRow);
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(ListBox2.Items[i].ToString(),System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            rw = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                rw[ListBox2.Items[i].ToString()] = " ";
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(rw);
        }
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3871934/81053

Answer (score 1):

You could use GridView's [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event with [`DataControlRowType.Header`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype.aspx):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
        DataTable tblProfiles = getProfiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            String header = grid.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            if (header.Length != 0)
            {
                DataRow drProfile = tblProfiles.AsEnumerable()
                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Field<String>("Profile_Name") == header);
                if (drProfile != null)
                    e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = drProfile.Field<String>("Tool_Tip");
            }
        }
    }
}

private DataTable getProfiles()
{
    // assuming SQL-Server
    var connectionString = "blah";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var sql = "SELECT Profile_Name, Tool_Tip FROM Profiles;";
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
        {
            var tblProfiles = new DataTable("Profiles");
            da.Fill(tblProfiles);
            return tblProfiles;
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Note that you need to add `using System.Linq;` for Linq-To-DataSet</sub>

Comment: Error 1: Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow.Cells' cannot be used like a method. Error 2:The name 'getDynamicTooltip' does not exist in the current context. In which case I assume getDynamicTooltip is a function. Can you kindly help.

Comment: @ArchanaB.R: Corrected, i'm currently in a VB.NET project. Therefore i've used  round brackets(VB) instead of square brackets(C#) ;)

Comment: It still with errors. Error 1: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' does not contain a definition for 'Tooltip' and no extension method 'Tooltip' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).  And Error2 is about the getDynamicTooltip.

Comment: @ArchanaB.R: I've meant `ToolTip` instead of `Tooltip` (sorry, i cannot test it here), but  google or intellisense would have been faster than posting here and waiting for my response ;) `getDynamicTooltip` must be implemented by you, haven't you read my comment at the end of my answer?

Comment: Yea thanks.. So for the getDynamicTootip should I store each column in different ListBox and equate their index and then use. In the screenshot that I have attached also shows a table in which I store tool-tip. Kindly help. This is the first time I am working on c#.

Comment: Haven't you noticed that your screenshot is too small? If you want it to be in the original size, you should post a link to the full image instead. How do you know which column has which headertext?

Comment: I am very sorry... U can find the image link in my edited question. thank you.

Comment: And I have also edit the question to include the code part to show How do I know which column has which headertext.

Comment: Thank you so much for yo time... I am sorry to inform that it is not working. It is not showing any errors. I have just copy pasted yo code and replaced connection string and proper table name. Also made sure that I have included `using System.Linq;` for Linq-To-DataSet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16047/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-archana-b-r)