# How to display Tooltip on GridView Row Hover

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hover, tooltip

I need to show a tooltip when mouse is placed on GridView Row (onmouseover)
I need to set the Tooltip content Dynamically in `GridView_RowData`

How can I Do this??

Can I Do this in `e.Row.Attributes.Add(...` ??

Comment: @krshekhar Can you please explain how ??

Comment: hope this url help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871934/tooltip-in-gridview

Comment: e.Row.Attributes.Add("title", "title value");

Comment: or from aspx as suggested by @saeedmirzaiesaran

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //use this way
        e.Row.ToolTip = "My FooBar tooltip";
         //or use this way
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("title", "My FooBar tooltip");
    }
 }
```

This will show tooltip for entire row..If you need to show on a particular control then find that control and set is `Tooltip` attribute to your own title...

Answer (score 0):

Can be Done like this. Here is the working copy.

What you need to do is, you have to find the control(for which you want to display `tooltip on hover of mouse`) inside the `Gridview` `OnRowDataBound` event and assign the `tooltip` text to the control.

```
protected void GridDepartment_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label LabelCoachName = e.Row.FindControl("LabelCoachName") as Label;
        LabelCoachName.ToolTip = LabelCoachName.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        'your dynamic data fill to e.row.tooltip
        e.Row.ToolTip = e.Row.Cells(1).Text & "-" & e.Row.Cells(3).Text
    End If
```