# display details of gridview on mousehover

Tags: asp.net, gridview, mouseover

I have a `gridview` and it is getting populated with the data properly. In the gridview there is a column displaying ownername. If I *hover* the mouse on the name of the owner contact number and email address should be visible like a tool tips.

How can I implement this in ASP.NET? I am using 3.5 framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tooltip in GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871934/tooltip-in-gridview)

Comment: Show the markup for your gridview, please.